# Linux rename batch files according to a list

Tags: linux, list, file, rename

I am looking to rename a bunch of files according to the names found in a separate list. Here is the situation:

Files:
file_0001.txt
file_0102.txt
file_ab42.txt

I want to change the names of these files according to a list of corresponding names that looks like :
0001     abc.01
0102     abc.02
ab42     def.01

I want to replace, for each file, the part of the name present in the first column of my list by the part in the second column:

```
file_0001.txt -> file_abc.01.txt
file_0102.txt -> file_abc.02.txt
file_ab42.txt -> file_def.01.txt
```

I looked into several mv, rename and such commands, but I only found ways to rename batch files according to a single pattern in the file name, not matching the changes with a list.

Does anyone has a example of script that I could use to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while read a b; do mv file_$a.txt $b;done < listfile
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.